# issue in list of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
class MyOwnClass:

  # list who contains the queries
  queries = []

  # a template dict
  template_query = {}
  template_query['name'] = 'mat'
  template_query['age'] = '12'

obj = MyOwnClass()

query = obj.template_query
query['name'] = 'sam'
query['age'] = '23'
obj.queries.append(query)

query2 = obj.template_query
query2['name'] = 'dj'
query2['age'] = '19'
obj.queries.append(query2)

print obj.queries
```

It gives me

```
[{'age': '19', 'name': 'dj'}, {'age': '19', 'name': 'dj'}]
```

while I expect to have

```
[{'age': '23'  , 'name': 'sam'}, {'age': '19', 'name': 'dj'}]
```

I thought to use a template for this list because I'm gonna to use it very often and there are some default variable who does not need to be changed.

Why does doing it the `template_query` itself changes? I'm new to python and I'm getting pretty confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is because you are pointing to the same dictionary each time ... and overwriting the keys ...

```
# query = obj.template_query - dont need this
query = {}
query['name'] = 'sam'
query['age'] = '23'
obj.queries.append(query)

query2 = {} #obj.template_query-dont need this
query2['name'] = 'dj'
query2['age'] = '19'
obj.queries.append(query2)
```

this should demonstrate your problem

```
>>> q = {'a':1}
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.append(q)
>>> q['a']=2
>>> lst
[{'a': 2}]
>>> lst.append(q)
>>> lst
[{'a': 2}, {'a': 2}]
```

you could implement your class differently

```
class MyOwnClass:
  # a template dict
  @property
  def template_query():
      return {'name':'default','age':-1}
```

this will make `obj.template_query` return a new dict each time

Comment: Thank you for  you're answer. The easiest way to fix it I think is to return the dict with a function as you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `query` and `query2` are both referring to the same object. `obj.template_query`, in this case.

Better to make a template factory:

```
def template_query(**kwargs):
    template =  {'name': 'some default value', 
                 'age': 'another default value', 
                 'car': 'generic car name'}
    template.update(**kwargs)
    return template
```

That creates a new dictionary every time it's called. So you can do:

```
>>> my_query = template_query(name="sam")
>>> my_query
{'name': 'sam', 'age': 'another default value', 'car': 'generic car name'}
```

Comment: great answer :) and way to encourage better coding practice in general

Answer (score 1):

You're copying the same dict into query2. Instead, you might want to create the needed dict by creating a function template_query() and constructing a new dict each time:

```
class MyOwnClass:

  # a template dict
  def template_query():
    d = {}
    d['name'] = 'mat'
    d['age'] = '12'
    d['car'] = 'ferrari'
    return d
```